# Access attribute of elements after table ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I have html table with cells and input fields inside cell:

```
<tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-even google-visualization-table-tr-sel">
   <td class="google-visualization-table-td"><input id="costRedovi" vr="2013-04-01" kol="John Deer n7" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
   <td class="google-visualization-table-td"><input id="costRedovi" vr="2013-04-01" kol="Laza Lazic" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
</tr>
```

Now I write a function:

```
new google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {

    $("#costRedovi").focusout(function() {
        console.log(this.attr('value'));


    });

});
```

so when table is ready to do some with focusout event... but i get: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'attr'` how I can get value from input element when table is ready? Also why I cant use jquery function here when I put jquery as the top source on the top of HTML page?

How I can solve this problem?

**What I exactly need?**
When google visualisation table is ready to fetch jquery `.focusout` event and to get some attributes from that input fields with ID=costRedovi...

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

you need to wrap `this` into jQuery wrapper like that:

```
console.log($(this).attr('value'));
```

Standard Javascript API doesn't consist od method such as `attr` and `this` is plain javascript object- it doesn't consist of jQuery methods. This is why you need to wrap it in `$()`.
You cannot have multiple ids with the same name, as well. id should be unique throughout the whole html document. Javascript won't process it properly in most cases. You should drop `focusout` event listener and just grab the values directly (but after making sure that your ids will be unique), eg.:

```
    console.log($('#costRedovi1').attr('value'));
    console.log($('#costRedovi2').attr('value'));
```

Comment: Although this will solve the correct usage of jQuery it doesn't answer the *on table load* problem (fyi).

Comment: so please explain better what you want

Comment: I must have input fields with same id or with some other attribute, so to fetch .focusout event

Comment: As I wrote: you cannot have the same multiple ids on the page. Try using class or some other custom attribute